# iOS placeholder text being cropped and font won't change

Tags: html, ios, positioning, font-size, placeholder

i have the following code to style a text input box for an iOS web app, but having 2 problems with it.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="search" name="search" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"
```

placeholder="Search...">

CSS:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
    color:#f00;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: Open Sans Condensed, sans-serif;
}

input.search {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
   color: #333;
   background: #e9e9e9;
   font: normal 2em Open Sans Condensed, sans-serif;
   width: 80%;
   height: 8em;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   -webkit-border-radius: 12px;

}
```

First issue is the Placeholder text is being cropped when the font-size is anything over 1em:
[image: http://www.screencast.com/t/SXg0LaXXHM]

Second issue is when typing a value into the text field, the font will not change from the default font size and font type:

[image: http://www.screencast.com/t/tfy6HoVL]

i've tried     `-webkit-appearance: none;`

please can anyone help?

Many thanks!

Comment: I've fixed the text cropping by adding:
    line-height:2em;

Still having a problem with the re-sizing of the font in the text entry though - any help on this anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Test this :

```
yourInputName::placeholder {
   overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: If the overflow property didnt get set from somewhere else (which the given code in the question doesnt show) your solution will not change anything as the default value of the overflow property is "visible" anyways.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered the first problem, it was caused by the input field font size being smaller than the placeholder font size.

Your CSS shows both at 2em, but check to see that the input field font size isn't being overridden to 1em somewhere else (as the problem seems to occur at placeholder fonts larger than 1em).